# How to integrate WeChat video call and chat to Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, wechat

I want to integrate WeChat api and want to use it for video chat and group hangout. Is there any ask or package for this ?

Comment: read wechat api documendation

Comment: I went through the process, but didn't found way to implement video chat.

Answer (score 0):

I made a code snippet for a python API to read WeChat messages (in a django app)

It also explains how to make a developer account etc

code: https://github.com/tawanda/django-wechat

### Summary

#### Create developer account

- head over to http://admin.wechat.com/debug/sandbox
- Click on Login
- Scan the QR code

You should see the sandbox developer page now